# Numbering rows within groups in a data frame but without considering the NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In stackoverflow there are several post asking about how to tagging specific combinations of levels among columns. However, I can't find how to do this but without considering the `NA`s. As an example:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   cat        val  
1  aaa 0.05638315  
2  aaa 0.25767250  
3  aaa NA  
4  aaa 0.46854928  
5  aaa 0.55232243  
6  bbb NA  
7  bbb 0.37032054  
8  bbb 0.48377074  
9  bbb 0.54655860  
10 bbb 0.81240262  
11 ccc 0.28035384  
12 ccc 0.39848790  
13 ccc 0.62499648  
14 ccc 0.76255108  
15 ccc 0.88216552")
```

I would expect this:

```
df
   cat        val id
1  aaa 0.05638315  1
2  aaa 0.25767250  2
3  aaa         NA NA
4  aaa 0.46854928  3
5  aaa 0.55232243  4
6  bbb         NA NA
7  bbb 0.37032054  1
8  bbb 0.48377074  2
9  bbb 0.54655860  3
10 bbb 0.81240262  4
11 ccc 0.28035384  1
12 ccc 0.39848790  2
13 ccc 0.62499648  3
14 ccc 0.76255108  4
15 ccc 0.88216552  5
```

Possible codes are those, however, they do not contemplate `NAs`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(cat) %>% mutate(id = row_number())

head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cat [2]
  cat       val    id
  <fct>   <dbl> <int>
1 aaa    0.0564     1
2 aaa    0.258      2
3 aaa   NA          3
4 aaa    0.469      4
5 aaa    0.552      5
6 bbb   NA          1
```

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)

DT[, id := seq_len(.N), by = cat]
df <- DT[, id := rowid(cat)]

head(df)
   cat        val id
1: aaa 0.05638315  1
2: aaa 0.25767250  2
3: aaa         NA  3
4: aaa 0.46854928  4
5: aaa 0.55232243  5
6: bbb         NA  1
```

Also, I wonder how to do if what I want is to start numbering from the first record, and from that, we numbering without considering the `NA`s. An example:

```
df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   cat        val  
1  aaa 0.05638315  
2  aaa 0.25767250  
3  aaa NA  
4  aaa 0.46854928  
5  aaa 0.55232243  
6  bbb NA  
7  bbb 0.37032054  
8  bbb 0.48377074  
9  bbb NA  
10 bbb 0.81240262  
11 ccc 0.28035384  
12 ccc 0.39848790  
13 ccc 0.62499648  
14 ccc 0.76255108  
15 ccc 0.88216552")
```

I would expect that:

```
df2
   cat      val id
1  aaa 0.056383  1
2  aaa 0.257673  2
3  aaa       NA  3
4  aaa 0.468549  4
5  aaa 0.552322  5
6  bbb       NA NA
7  bbb 0.370321  1
8  bbb 0.483771  2
9  bbb       NA  3
10 bbb 0.812403  4
11 ccc 0.280354  1
12 ccc 0.398488  2
13 ccc 0.624996  3
14 ccc 0.762551  4
15 ccc 0.882166  5
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You were close. Try `setDT(df)[!is.na(val), id := seq_len(.N), cat]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak the suggestions that you have to get the desired output :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(id = replace(row_number() - cumsum(is.na(val)), is.na(val), NA))

#   cat       val    id
#   <chr>   <dbl> <int>
# 1 aaa    0.0564     1
# 2 aaa    0.258      2
# 3 aaa   NA         NA
# 4 aaa    0.469      3
# 5 aaa    0.552      4
# 6 bbb   NA         NA
# 7 bbb    0.370      1
# 8 bbb    0.484      2
# 9 bbb    0.547      3
#10 bbb    0.812      4
#11 ccc    0.280      1
#12 ccc    0.398      2
#13 ccc    0.625      3
#14 ccc    0.763      4
#15 ccc    0.882      5
```

This can be also be written in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, id:= replace(seq_len(.N) - cumsum(is.na(val)), is.na(val), NA), cat]
```

and base R :

```
df$id <- with(df, replace(ave(val, cat, FUN = function(x) 
                  seq_along(x) - cumsum(is.na(x))), is.na(val), NA))
```

The logic is to create an `id` variable which is current row number in the group minus the number of `NA`'s that have occurred till that time.

---

For updated `df2` to consider the `NA` only in first row we can use :

```
df2 %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(id = replace(row_number() - is.na(first(val)),1* is.na(first(val)), NA))

#   cat       val    id
#   <chr>   <dbl> <int>
# 1 aaa    0.0564     1
# 2 aaa    0.258      2
# 3 aaa   NA          3
# 4 aaa    0.469      4
# 5 aaa    0.552      5
# 6 bbb   NA         NA
# 7 bbb    0.370      1
# 8 bbb    0.484      2
# 9 bbb   NA          3
#10 bbb    0.812      4
#11 ccc    0.280      1
#12 ccc    0.398      2
#13 ccc    0.625      3
#14 ccc    0.763      4
#15 ccc    0.882      5
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah for your time and diligence. Your reply is very complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict a `:=` assignment to certain rows using the first argument of `[.data.table`:

```r
setDT(df)
df[complete.cases(val), id := seq_len(.N), by = .(cat)]
```